# requestAnimationFrame + apply

Tags: requestanimationframe

Var T=0

...

var TestClass = new Class()

```
    TestClass.extend({
        init: function () {
            this.TT = T;
            T++
        }
    });

    TestClass.include({
        animate: function () {
            A = this
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                A.animate();
                console.log(A.TT)
            });
        }
    });
```

...

```
    var can1 = new TestClass();
    var can2 = new TestClass();
    var can3 = new TestClass();
```

...

```
    var can1.animate()
    var can2.animate()
    var can3.animate()
```

So it works only for can3.
console: >>2

if i will do:

```
    TestClass.include({
        animate: function ()
        {
            console.log(this.TT)
        }
    });

    var can1 = new TestClass();
    var can2 = new TestClass();
    var can3 = new TestClass();

    function G() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            can1.animate()
            can2.animate()
            can3.animate()
            G()
        });
    }
    G()
```

it will works correctly, but how i can do requestAnimationFrame inside each of TestClass?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. So make it.
Try it?
https://github.com/mixed/requestAnimationFrameInterval

```
TestClass.include({
    animate: function () {
        A = this
        window.requestAnimationFrameInterval(function () {
            A.animate();
            console.log(A.TT);
        });
    }
});

var can1 = new TestClass();
var can2 = new TestClass();
var can3 = new TestClass();

var can1.animate()
var can2.animate()
var can3.animate()
```

`